# Ставится ли запятая перед "что" в предложении "он спрашивает что ты думаешь по поводу..."

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая перед "что" в предложении "Он спрашивает что ты думаешь по поводу..."?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Да, конечно. 
Это сложноподчиненное предложение, запятая, отделяющая подчиненное предложение от главного, необходима.